# padding with preceding zeros

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a

```
list1 = {1, 23, 4, 14} (*max entry is 99*)
```

and want to create from that another

```
list2 = {01, 23, 04, 14}
```

preceding zeros if the number is less than `10`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `NumberForm` should work...

Comment: @Yves Klett: can you please show the solution with `NumberForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IntegerString[list1, 10, 2]
```

Note that the resulting list consists of strings and not numbers. But maybe that is sufficient for your application?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, from the numbers I produce strings for labels.

Comment: Okay, then it's the way to go! =) You're welcome.